# Weird behaviour with len and str.splitlines()

Tags: python, string, typeerror, python-3.4

I'm making a HTTP request with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and I want to make a Simple Response Object that parses my data. The problem I'm having is the following. When passing the response object to my ApiResponse I split the Response.text in lines, to count them and know if it has multiple or single lines. the problem is that the splitlines list gives me an error when applying len() to that but in the console it works ok.

**This is the class:**

```
class ApiResponse(object):
pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+): ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)')  # original ([a-zA-Z]+)\: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
response_type = ResponseType.OK
response_mode = ResponseMode.SINGLE

def __init__(self, r: resp):
    self.r = r
    self.parse(r)
    self.data = None

def parse(self, r: resp):
    """
    Method that parses the response from the API
    :param r:Response
    """
    if r.status_code != 200:
        self.response_type = ResponseType.ERR

    if len(r.text.splitlines()) > 1:
        self.response_mode = ResponseMode.MULTI

    for line in r.text.splitlines():
        match = self.pattern.search(line)
        if match is None:
            break
        print(match.group(1, 2))  # REMOVE testing
        self.response_type = ResponseType[match.group(1)]
```

**This is the console output:**

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
>>> import requests
>>> from clickapy.response import ApiResponse
>>> r = requests.get(API_URL, {'user': USER, 'password': PASS, 'api_id': API_ID})
>>> api_response = ApiResponse(r)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/eefret/PycharmProjects/clickapy/clickapy/response.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.parse(r)
  File "/home/eefret/PycharmProjects/clickapy/clickapy/response.py", line 43, in parse
    if len(r.text.splitlines()) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
>>> len(r.text.splitlines())
1
```

Why this is happening? It doesn't make sense to me, I'm executing the same pieces of code, any help or feedback is welcome.

Comment: don't use `is` or `is not` with numbers! Don't use class attributes as predefined instance attributes.

Comment: unrelated but it should be `if r.status_code != 200:`

Comment: Corrected but still doing the same

Comment: This is copy-pasted from actual interpreter output, right? Because by far the most likely explanation is that the code actually says `len(r.text.splitlines)`. Check for a `response.pyc` file and delete it if there is one, and recheck the `response.py` file to make sure that line looks the way you think it's supposed to.

Comment: Without being able to run and reproduce it is going to be hard to suggest anything, also if you are parsing html you might want to use a html parser

Comment: Im using the requests library I included a link in the question so its not a problem from the api, also im requesting an API its returning plain text not HTML

Comment: Does it only happen with that URL which needs account data, or can you reproduce it with a public URL like `http://google.com` as well, so that we can try it ourselves?

Comment: good point Stefan Pochmann, and also, could you please put a `print(r, type(r))` before your `if len(r.text.splitlines()) > 1:`?

Comment: Yeah any URL was giving the same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine (all credits to **`Mariano Garcia`**) has helped me and as he doesn't have SO account I will post what solved this behavior, my console was enforcing `utf-8` but internally the text still had to be encoded so what solved this changing this `if len(r.text.splitlines()) > 1:` to this `if len(r.text.encode("utf-8").splitlines()) > 1:`

The complete code :

```
class ApiResponse(object):
    pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+): ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)')  # original ([a-zA-Z]+)\: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
    response_type = ResponseType.OK
    response_mode = ResponseMode.SINGLE

    def __init__(self, r: resp):
        self.r = r
        self.parse(r)
        self.data = None

    def parse(self, r: resp):
        """
        Method that parses the response from the API
        :param r:Response
        """
        if r.status_code != 200:
            self.response_type = ResponseType.ERR

        if len(r.text.encode("utf-8").splitlines()) > 1:
            self.response_mode = ResponseMode.MULTI

        for line in r.text.splitlines():
            match = self.pattern.search(line)
            if match is None:
                break
            print(match.group(1, 2))  # REMOVE testing
            self.response_type = ResponseType[match.group(1)]
```